# Why POT textures work slower than non-pot?

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I use following function to load textures

```
public static int loadTexture(Bitmap bmp)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        //GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(textureHandle[0]);
        //adapt texture to POT
        int adaptedWidth= (int) Math.pow(2,Math.ceil(Math.log(bmp.getWidth())/Math.log(2d)));
        int adaptedHeight= (int) Math.pow(2,Math.ceil(Math.log(bmp.getHeight())/Math.log(2d)));
        Log.d("texture",adaptedWidth+","+adaptedHeight);

        Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, adaptedWidth, adaptedHeight, false);
        Log.d("asize",tmp.getWidth()+","+tmp.getHeight());
        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tmp, 0);
        //GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
        tmp.recycle();
        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        //bmp.recycle();
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }
    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

I got 14-17 fps with this code.Hovever if I load my bitmap(which is non POT) directly without adaptation to POT.FPS jumps to 28-30.I thought POT textures should work faster then non-POT.Is there explanation for this?

UPD:Rendering code:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //curScale=modelMatrix[SCALE_X];
    TimeMeasurer.reset();
    long curTS= SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long frameRenderTime=curTS-ts;
    //Log.d("renderer","FPS:"+1000.0/frameRenderTime);
    Log.d("renderer","frame render time:"+frameRenderTime);
    ts=curTS;
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (piecesMesh!=null) {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(MVPMatrix,0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix,0,projMatrix,0,modelMatrix,0);
        drawPassivePieces();
        drawActivePieces();
        if (helper!=null) {
            drawHelper();
        }
    }
    TimeMeasurer.measure("onDrawFrame execution time:");
}
private void drawPassivePieces() {
    //shadows
    shadowProgram.useProgram();
    shadowProgram.setUniforms(MVPMatrix,textureMaskId);
    shadowMesh.bindPieceData(shadowProgram,false);
    shadowMesh.drawPieces(false);
    shadowMesh.disableAttributes(shadowProgram);
    //pieces
    piecesProgram.useProgram();
    piecesProgram.setUniforms(MVPMatrix, textureImageId, textureMaskId);
    piecesMesh.bindPieceData(piecesProgram,false);
    piecesMesh.drawPieces(false);
    piecesMesh.disableAttributes(piecesProgram);

}
private void drawActivePieces() {
    //shadows
    shadowProgram.useProgram();
    shadowProgram.setUniforms(MVPMatrix,textureMaskId);
    shadowMesh.bindPieceData(shadowProgram,true);
    shadowMesh.drawPieces(true);
    shadowMesh.disableAttributes(shadowProgram);
    //pieces
    piecesProgram.useProgram();
    piecesProgram.setUniforms(MVPMatrix, textureImageId, textureMaskId);
    piecesMesh.bindPieceData(piecesProgram,true);
    piecesMesh.drawPieces(true);
    piecesMesh.disableAttributes(piecesProgram);
}
public void drawHelper() {
    helperProgram.useProgram();
    helper.bindData(helperProgram);
    helper.draw();
    helper.disableAttributes(helperProgram);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a detailed performance analysis, it's not really possible to do more than speculate.

One likely cause is that your rendering is limited by memory bandwidth of texture sampling. If you make the texture larger, the total amount of memory accessed is larger, causing the slowdown.

Or, very related to the above, your cache hit rate for texture sampling drops if the sampled texels are spread out farther in memory, which happens when you upscale the texture. Lower cache hit rate means slower performance.

You really shouldn't artificially make the texture larger than necessary, unless it's needed due to the limited NPOT support in ES 2.0, and the hardware you use does not advertise the OES_texture_npot extension. I doubt that anybody has made hardware that prefers POT textures in a long time.

Comment: Added rendering code.Also I did some measurements:
NPOT:
frame rendering time:39
onDraw execution time:8
POT:
frame rendering time:73
onDraw execution time:8
So the problem is in drawing time which I assume is the difference between `frame rendering time` and `onDraw execution time`

Comment: Also I have changed the texture loading code so it doesn't scale up bitmap but just draw my texture into new larger empty bimap - same result.

Comment: @undefined All of these observations are consistent with my theory.

Comment: According to your theory there is nothing I can do to fix this.Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what happened but my fps back to 30+.I did some adjustments so my texture coordinates don't go beyond actual image size.I don't know why but this strongly affects rendering time
Thanks everyone!

Comment: @undefined Again, more evidence that my explanation is the correct one. If you have a larger texture, but sample only the part of it that corresponds to the smaller one, the GPU needs to only read that part during sampling. Meaning that the required memory bandwidth and the cache hit rates will be the same between the two cases.

Comment: Thanks man.I marked your comment as accepted answer.Can't vote till my reputation reaches 15.

Answer (score 0):

There are big advantages to using POT textures. In OpenGLES 2.0 they allow you to use mipmaps and useful texture addressing modes like repeat. You also can utilize memory more efficiently because lots of implementations allocate memory as if your texture is POT anyway.

However, in this case where you just take a non-POT texture and scale it up, I'd expect performance to be slightly worse as a result. You're missing out on the big potential win because you're not using mipmaps. By using a larger texture you're just asking more of the GPU's texture cache because the useful parts of the image are now more spread out in memory than they were previously.

Another way to look at it is that in the absence of mipmapping, big textures are going to perform worse than little textures, and your rescaling process is just making your texture bigger.

I'm surprised the difference is so noticeable though - are you sure that your rescaling codepath isn't doing anything unexpected like resizing too large, or picking a different texture format or filter mode?

Comment: I use my bitmap as source in the createScaledBitmap so pixel format should be the same.No filters are applied.
My texture size is 1792x1536; adapted size:2048x2048
I draw 2220 polygons with one fragment shader(using two textures) and then 2220 polygons with other fragment shader.
Its surprise for me too why the same code depends on texture size so heavily.